# Xubuntu 12.04 USB wifi adaptor

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, xubuntu

My friend has an old laptop that had XP on so I've installed Xubuntu 12.04 but when I tried to install the additional drivers for my USB wifi adaptor - a AVM Fritz with Broadcom 7xxx chipset (I dont remember the exact chipset) it crashed the laptop.

So what USB wifi adaptor do I need to buy that will definitely work with Xubuntu 12.04?

Im using Xubuntu 12.04 because its an old laptop and it has a none pea CPU (or some similar acronym) so it wont run Ubuntu 12 or the later versions of the other distros.

The USB adaptor I currently have isn't a new one, it is several years old. Is there a database anywhere listing what hardware works with Linux?

Thanks

Comment: Would you care to troubleshoot the Fritz? Please insert the device and run and post: lsusb Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here at this website

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB

and

from Ubuntu website

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Comment: Just out of Interest which one? just in case i need one one day.

Comment: Ive not had chance to get it yet but Im going for a TP Link TL-WN721N or TL-WN727N or TL-WN821N

Comment: Ok ill mark those brands down and check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did get my Fritz usb stick to work on my notebook, but it was a pain. You can get the drivers off of the AVM website in Berlin. But the reception was not very good and it was not multi canal, so I bought a little 'Penguin' type 'TPE-N150USB', which works great. I think it only cost me some 16,00 Euros, but you could get them off the _bay website.

Mike